# What is "version" property of Collection+JSON

Tags: json, collections

I am reading some info about Collection+JSON. And i have found that every collection needs to have version property. But from the docs it is not clear to me what it should have contain.

> The version SHOULD be a child property of the collection collection element.
>       It SHOULD be a STRING data type. For this release, the version SHOULD be set to 1.0.

So what is that value? Is it version of Collection+JSON format, or version of my API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is version of Collection+Json format.